# Couchbase N1QL search text with line break

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

I am trying to query the db with following n1ql query

```
where any content in `test-mcms`.contents satisfies content.content LIKE \"%Sic%\" END
```

the code is working well unless there is a line break `\n`

```
"blah Sic blah"
```

the above is okay.

```
"blah Sic blah \n\n blah"
```

bot not this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it has to do with how you're escaping your string.  Can you try this instead?:

```
where any content in `test-mcms`.contents satisfies content.content LIKE '%Sic%' END
```

Best,